# Removing only certain types of characters regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Edit: Sorry, should have given more information

Is it possible to replace only the english text here?

```
{ "question": "本能", "answers":[ "ほんのうInstinct" ] },
```

I want it to just be `{ "question": "本能", "answers":[ "めがね" ] },` and keep the other english text.

Tried [A-Za-z]+ and it works for all english text, but I don't know how to select a certain section. I'm using find and replace on notepad+

Comment: 'めがねGlasses'.replace(/[A-z]/g, '')

Comment: @Laurianti That should be `.replace(/[A-Za-z]/g, '')`. [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970).

Comment: @PierceJ What is the regex flavor/programming language?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using Notepad+ find and replace at the moment. Each line is different

Comment: @PierceJ Then, really, you may use that simple regex, `[A-Za-z]+`. Try.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works perfect, but how would I include the quotation and the brace so that it only works with this part of the line?

Comment: Wait,  what do you mean? I thought you need to remove the letters anywhere in the document.

Comment: The full line is this: { "question": "本能", "answers":[ "ほんのうInstinct" ] }, sorry I should have mentioned it. I only want to remove the english after answers

Comment: Please edit the question mentioning what you really need and what you tried and what is wrong with the current approach. Also, add a relevant tag.

Comment: I did, sorry. Thanks for your help though

Comment: The real problem is the fact it is a JSON file. You should really think of using a JSON parser here. If you think you may use a regex, then please define the *end* boundary for the pattern. The starting boundary is `"answers":`, but when should it stop matching?

Comment: Its actually a json file saved as a plain txt file

Comment: Ok, try `(?:\G(?!^)|"answers"\s*:\s*\[")[^"]*?\K[a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: That did not work for me, said 0 occurrences

Comment: You have a space between `[` and `"`, so use `(?:\G(?!^)|"answers"\s*:\s*\[\s*")[^"]*?\K[a-zA-Z]+`. I do not know what the indentation is there, in your file, just add `\s*` anywhere where spaces may occur. Besides, it is not clear if you have just "trailing" English letters, or there can be `"SOMEめがねwordsがねhere"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|"answers"\s*:\s*\[\s*")[^"]*?\K[a-zA-Z]+
```

and replace with an empty string.

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|"answers"\s*:\s*\[\s*")` - the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) `"answers"` substring, 0+ whitespaces, `:`,  0+ whitespaces, `[`, 0+ whitespaces, `"` (see `"answers"\s*:\s*\[\s*"`)
- `[^"]*?` - any 0+ chars other than `"`, as *few* as possible (as `*?` is a lazy quantifier)
- `\K` - a match reset operator discarding all text matched so far from the match buffer
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters

Test:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this is your regex: `/[A-Za-z]*/g`

```js
var s = '":[ "めがねGlasses" ] },'

console.log(s.replace(/[A-Za-z]*/g, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace everything that matches `/[a-z]/gi` by an empty string.

The flags `g` and `i` respectively means that you want to match multiple times and you want to be case insensitive.

You also could use `\w` shortcut which stand for word character, but this will also match `[0-9_]` which you may not want to delete.

[Here is a working exemple of the regex.](https://regex101.com/r/kvQLud/1)